# Derivation of the maximum entropy distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

I am reading a book and having trouble following something. The problem is to try to maximize  the differential entropy $-\int_{0}^{\infty}p(r)\log p(r)$ under the constraints that $\int_{0}^{\infty}p(r)=1$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}rp(r)=\mu_{r}$. The book then just straightaway states that the result is an exponential distribution. I tried to prove this to myself but got stuck, it has been a while since I did any math so I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic.

Here's how far I have gotten. I first wrote the lagrangian

$L=-\int_{0}^{\infty}p(r)\log p(r)+\lambda_{1}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}p(r)-1\right)+\lambda_{2}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}rp(r)-\mu_{r}\right)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$

Now here is where I started getting a bit lost, I wasn't sure how to differentiate under the integral so I assumed that the integral was actually a sum over $p(r_{i})$ and differentiated $L$ w.r.t to $p(r_{i})$. Is this correct? What is the proper and general way to solve such differentials?

Moving along, after differentiation (assuming it was a sum) I got the following

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p}=-\log p(r)-1+\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}r=0$

$\implies p(r)=e^{\lambda_{2}r+\lambda_{1}-1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda_{1}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}p(r)-1=0$

$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\lambda_{2}r+\lambda_{1}-1}dr=1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda_{2}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}rp(r)-1=0$

$\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}re^{\lambda_{2}r+\lambda_{1}-1}dr=1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$

But now as per my knowledge, the definite integrals in (3) and (4) should equal infinity, but that doesn't help me and so I am stuck? I am sure I am making some very basic conceptual mistake. Can someone please help me with this solution? Thanks.

Comment: Somehow, an integral sans differentials looks to me like an unclosed parenthesis...

Comment: definite integrals (3) and (4) are not necessarily equal to infinity. Consider $\lambda_2 = -1$ and $\lambda_1 = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-a x} \mathrm d x = \frac{1}{a}$ for $a>0$.

$\int_0^\infty x \mathrm e^{-a x} \mathrm d x$ may be evaluated by integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten my integrals. Just another silly doubt, seeing that I have $e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and not $e^{-\lambda_1 x}$ can I say let $\lambda_1=-c$ and then solve $\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-c x}$ and then later substitute back $\lambda_1$? Is there another better method?

Answer (score 2):

Your question about the infinite integrals has already been answered (note that you can make your life easier by absorbing the $1$ into $\lambda_1$), so I'll just answer your question about how to systematically optimize such an integral. The general theory for this sort of thing is the [calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations), the main result of which is the Euler-Lagrange equation. However, since your integral depends only on $p$ and not on the derivative of $p$, the Euler-Lagrange equation just reduces to $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial p}=0$ (where $\mathcal L$ is the Lagrangian density, i.e. the integrand), so your calculation is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about calculus of variations.