# What is the maixmum entropy distribution for positive reals given the average and variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, entropy

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) that the maximum entropy distribution for the set of positive reals given the average of the logarithm and its variance is the log-normal distribution.

However, what is the maximum entropy distribution if we slightly change the constraints to just the average and variance of the variable (without the logarithm)?

Comment: The page you linked to says that the exponential distribution is the maximum entropy distribution among all continuous distributions supported in $[0,\infty)$ that have a specified mean.

Comment: @Snaw but that will not work if you know the variance (and it is not equal to the known mean).  Wikipedia then points to the paywalled https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055060 which says in its abstract *"When the range is $[0,\infty)$, the maximum-entropy distribution exists if, and only if, $\mu_2 \leq 2 \mu_1^2$ , and a table is given which enables the maximum-entropy distribution to be computed. The case $\mu_2 > 2 \mu_1^2$ is discussed in some detail."*

Comment: @Henry I see. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question, but I am not convinced by the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598608/what-is-the-maximum-entropy-distribution-for-a-continuous-random-variable-on-0